# pass scanf value to struct pointer Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault, scanf

All I want to do is a basic printing with a struct pointer using user input. I got a `segmentation fault` when I try to do with below code. I'm new to c, thanks anyway.

```
typedef struct {
    int *licenseNum;
    char *name;
    char *region;
} City;

typedef struct {
    struct Node *current;
    struct Node *head;
    struct Node *tail;
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *secondNext;
    City *data;
} Node;


int main()
{
    Node *node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    City *city = malloc(sizeof(City));
    puts("License number of the City: ");
    scanf("%d", &(node -> data -> licenseNum));
    printf("%d", node -> data -> licenseNum);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't set `data` in `node`.

```
Node * node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
City * city = malloc(sizeof(City));
// node->data is not yet defined!
// It has a random value! You must first initialize it:
node->data = city;
```

Also you shouldn't use `malloc` here as memory allocated by `malloc` has random values. Only use `malloc` if you for sure initialize all the pointers in a `struct` with meaningful values prior to using them. It's much safer to use `calloc`:

```
Node * node = calloc(1, sizeof(Node));
City * city = calloc(1, sizeof(City));
node->data = city;
```

`calloc` works like `malloc`, but it guarantees that the returned memory is all set to zero (all int values are `0`, all pointers are `NULL`). The first argument of `calloc` (`1` in the code above) is the number of items you want to allocate, here it is just one. E.g. `calloc(5, sizeof(City))` would allocate memory for 5 cities in a single block, e.g.:

```
Cities * cities = calloc(5, sizeof(City));
cities[0].name = "New York";
cities[1].name = "London";
// ... and so on
```

Comment: Shouldn't he be using `free(node)` and `free(city)` to free the dynamically allocated resources?

Comment: @SatyaPawan Yes, he should, but that wasn't part of the question. This would be part of the question "Why does my code leak memory?" ;-) And leaking memory is not necessarily critical in an app that just performs one operation and then quits as on quit, all allocated memory of an app is always returned to the OS and thus implicitly freed, so what different would it make to call `free` twice right before the app quits? It would make no difference. If you plan to keep your app running for hours, you have to budget with memory of course - or accept that your app needs GBs of it :-P

Comment: @Mecki Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize `node->data`.

Answer (score 0):

You allocated memory for `node`, but not for `node->data`.

You probably wanted to do this: `node->data = city`